# .htaccess rule to mask part of the url with a other string

Tags: .htaccess

I want to mask part of the URL using .htaccess rewrite rule such that I can visit my WordPress URL

`http://127.0.0.1/test/wp-admin/index.php`

with the below URL

`http://127.0.0.1/test/wp-admin/SomeString/index.php`

So I need a .htaccess rule which treats wp-admin/SomeString as wp-admin.

Please help me on this as I have wasted many hours since I have very less knowledge of .htaccess

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess code in your question; as part of your efforts; Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your response, I have tried this code and it worked for me  `RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.{6})(/?)(.*) wp-admin/$3`  where 6 is the length of the string.